# Passive harmonic filter: Why Immensely Hot and Humming

Tags: transformer, filter, saturation, harmonics

I encountered a passive harmonic filter, PHF with highly non linear loads, i.e. variable frequency drive, VFD (most of the time running 50Hz) serving an induction motor.

[image: PFH full view]
[image: PFH schematic]
[image: Inside view]

I believe that it is a commonly used resonant shunt filter to eliminate the 5th harmonic.

The enclosure housing the PHF has a ventilation fan, but still always (the reason why I am writing here) very HOT! Up to the extent that the contactors, wires have melted/discolorated/burnt mark etc

[image: Fan, but still very hot. Bubbling insulation]
[image: Thermoscan shows 86C!]

I suspect of the over saturation of the 3 phase transformer (V_phase2phase=415V), I believe acts as an isolation transformer-cum-line reactor. The capacitors are still in good condition (not bulging of the caps), but the winding insulation of the transformer is discoloured.

[image: Sagging insulation]
[image: Discouloured connectors] 
[image: Capacitors]

Any help to do further diagnostic is welcomed. I will conduct a harmonic assessment with a Fluke power analyser next week.

Comment: Is the motor and/or VSD overloaded?

Comment: Also, have you used the thermal camera to make sure it's not just a hot joint?

Comment: Does it get hot off-load?

Comment: @Li-aungYip: thanks for the comment. This filter has been installed for the past two years, and the motor & VSD are of 30kW, may not be undersized issue(I'll confirm again). Not sure if it's overloaded, most likely not as it is a factory designed and other similar units are not facing the same issue. Will need to check again if it's under-designed. How may I know if it's not just a hot joint? And it's not hot off load....

Comment: and @Andyaka: thanks for the comment. It's not hot off load, as the motor and filter are OFF. Why do you say/suspect otherwise?

Comment: I'll try again.... Is it running hot when the loading is light. I.e. does it get warmer on heavier loads?

Comment: @Andyaka: the load is constant and there's isn't any variable load exerts on the motor, and thus the VFD. Thanks a lot.

Comment: A 'hot joint' means a 'high resistance joint', i.e. a joint which has become dirty, loose, or corroded. If a connection on one phase is much hotter than the other two phases, you likely have a hot joint. You could confirm that by measuring the joint resistance with a micro-ohm tester (i.e. a Megger "Ductor".)

Comment: That bright white spot on the leftmost phase looks promising. It does appear that you have developed a high resistance joint right there. You're going to want to do an end to end resistance check on that line -  it may need to be replaced.